# Program just filled up my memory and started filling up swap in Xubuntu

Tags: memory, ubuntu

Is there a way to find out what process or what is filling up the memory? I just wrote a program that seems to fill it up rather quickly and not release it afterwards.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  Are you looking for help finding a memory leak in your code (if so, show us your code) or are you asking how do you generally determine which running process is exhausting system memory (if so, go to superuser.com)?

Comment: I'm asking if a linux utility exists that would help determine which running thread within a program that I wrote is causing the memory leaks, as for showing you the code, there's a lot, not sure what to show. I think this is a programming issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use top or htop (nicer view).